# How to change the currency symbol look of backslash to real backslash look

Tags: python, currency-format

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above, Python shows me the Korean Currency symbol instead of a real backslash `\`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I generally see this on computers using East Asian character sets (Japanese in my case). Do you see this only in Python or also in other applications?

Comment: In other applications too- Including chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Windows 10 displaying \ ‎as ‎¥ on the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%c2%a5-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Thanks alot, i figured it out.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question. It may help others in the future.