# Backslash ( \ ) not displaying properly in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have not been able to find a solution to this after days of researching: instead of backslash (`\`), the character displayed in console output is some other one as seen in this picture:

[image: seen in this picture]

When I copy and paste it into other applications it displays as a backslash. Eclipse text file encoding is set to UTF-8, the same is set in run configuration.

Comment: It looks like you are using an asian region setting as the default for your machine. Are you using Windows 10 1809 or newer? You can try to enable the Beta Unicode UTF-8 feature.

Comment: Which is the replacement character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it turned out to be a mistake on my part, some time ago I was working on hiragana>arabic translator and used font with japaneese characters, changed it now to default windows and everything works.

Comment: where/how did you change it to default Windows?

Comment: @mael' You mean in eclipse? by default Windows (font) I mean Segoe UI. You can change it in Window>Preferences>Colors and font

Comment: i meant whatever you were referring to since it wasn’t clear

Answer (score -1):

Eclipse likely uses `\` as an escape character, so you can try doubling it up like this `\\` where you need to show just one, `\\\\` where you need to show two, etc.

If escaping isn't the issue, you may be able to find helpful in formation [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1167662/why-is-windows-10-displaying-as-%C2%A5-on-the-command-line). You can try to:

> - Open **Control Panel**
> - Select **Region**
> - Go to the **Administrative** tab
> - Confirm your **Language for non-Unicode programs** is set to `English (United States)` - or wherever you need it to be.

Comment: "\\" produces this character seen on the picture.

Comment: @marciopol alright I've added a bit to the answer; it seems that having ¥ in place of backslash(es) is a common thing in Windows 10.

Comment: unfortunately that did not fix the issue